# after npm install -g create-react-app command is not working?

Tags: reactjs

after completing create-react-app command it shows :

```
added 1951 packages, and audited 1952 packages in 3m

135 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities.
```

it only shows 1 folder and 2 JSON file:

1. node modules.
2. package-lock.json
3. package.json.

Contents of `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "app-ok",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  }
}
```

script written. no script tag or any other.

and after giving 'npm start' command, I get a "script-start missing" error. I have been searching a lot on google but cant figure it out what is wrong.

I have uninstalled node 2-3 times and tried to do it in proper way again and again but nothing is working.

The error is:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\react\1stapp/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react\1stapp\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-15T06_10_59_725Z-debug.log
```

Comment: you don't have to install it. Just try `npx create-react-app <name-of-your-app>`

Comment: did that .npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\react/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\react\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-15T07_47_05_131Z-debug.log

Comment: im getting this error.

Comment: remove your node js application , clear the cache , reinstall node js any stable version, then try "npx create-react-app <name-of-your-app>"

If it is urgent then install yarn and try yarn create react-app my-app